# How to set and use variables in cloud-init?

Tags: linux, curl, github-api, cloud-init

I am trying to call an API and get a token to be used in the next API call at `runcmd` during `cloud-config` as part of Azure VMSS deployment with Terraform. How this can be achieved in `cloud-init`?

This is what I have tried, and it fails.

```
- [su, runner-admin, -c, 'REG_TOKEN=$(curl -sX POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token ${var.runner_manage_token}" https://api.github.com/orgs/${var.github_organisation}/actions/runners/registration-token | jq .token --raw-output)']
- [su, runner-admin, -c, '/actions-runner/config.sh --url https://github.com/${var.github_organisation} --token $${REG_TOKEN} --runnergroup ${var.runner_group}']
```

Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Thanks

Comment: How does it fail? Were there any warnings/errors in the log file? Do these commands  achieve the desired result from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up using `write_files` in `cloud-init` to solve my issue like this:

```
  write_files:    
    - path: /run/create-runner.sh
      content: |
        #!/bin/bash
        REG_TOKEN=$(curl -sX POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token ${var.runner_manage_token}" https://api.github.com/orgs/${var.github_organisation}/actions/runners/registration-token | jq .token --raw-output)
        /actions-runner/config.sh --unattended --url https://github.com/${var.github_organisation} --token $${REG_TOKEN} --runnergroup ${var.runner_group} --labels ${var.runner_labels} --replace
      owner: 'runner-admin'
      permissions: '0700'
      defer: true
```

And then run it in `runcmd`:

```
  runcmd:
  - [mkdir, '/actions-runner']
  - cd /actions-runner
  - [curl, -o, 'actions-runner.tar.gz', -L, 'https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v${var.runner_version}/actions-runner-linux-x64-${var.runner_version}.tar.gz']
  - [tar, -xzf, 'actions-runner.tar.gz']
  - [chmod, -R, 777, '/actions-runner']
  - [su, runner-admin, -c, /run/create-runner.sh]
  - ./svc.sh install runner-admin
  - ./svc.sh start
  - [rm, '/actions-runner/actions-runner.tar.gz']
```